# How to set listview row clickable only one time in android?

Tags: android, listview

Explanation:
           I have a listview in my fragment. When I click one of the row of the listview it goes to another activity.In listview,I got the data from the adapter.
Inside the adapter view,I set the setOnClick().

Problem is when I click one of the row multiple time it is opening multiple activity.I want to restrict only one time click on the particular row over the listview item.

Here is my fragment where I get the listview and set the adapter-

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    public static String key_updated = "updated", key_description = "description", key_title = "title", key_link = "link", key_url = "url", key_name = "name", key_description_text = "description_text";
    private static String url = "";

    List<String> lst_key = null;
    List<JSONObject> arr_completed = null;
    List<String> lst_key2 = null;

    List<JSONObject> lst_obj = null;
    List<String> list_status = null;
    ListView completed_listview;
    int PagerLength = 0,exeption_flag=0;

    View rootView;
    private ViewPager pagerRecentMatches;
    private ImageView imgOneSliderRecent;
    private ImageView imgTwoSliderRecent;
    private ImageView imgThreeSliderRecent;
    private ImageView imgFourSliderRecent;
    private ImageView imgFiveSliderRecent;
    private ImageView imgSixSliderRecent;
    private ImageView imgSevenSliderRecent;
    private ImageView imgEightSliderRecent;

    LinearLayout selector_dynamic;
    LinearLayout Recent_header_layout;
    FrameLayout adbar;
    String access_token = "";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    int current_pos=0,status_flag=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        findViews();

        selector_dynamic = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.selectors_dynamic);
        adbar = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adbar);
        new AddLoader(getContext()).LoadAds(adbar);

        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        access_token = activity.getMyData();

        sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("HomePref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        if (access_token == null || access_token=="") {
            url = "https://api.litzscore.com/rest/v2/recent_matches/?access_token=" + sharedPreferences.getString("access_token", null) + "&card_type=summary_card";

        } else {
            editor.putString("access_token", access_token);
            editor.commit();
            url = "https://api.litzscore.com/rest/v2/recent_matches/?access_token=" + access_token + "&card_type=summary_card";
        }
        completed_listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.completed_listview);


        Recent_header_layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Recent_header_layout);

        Recent_header_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if(!Utils.isNetworkConnected(getContext())){
            dialog_popup();
        }
        else{
            new TabJson().execute();
        }
        pagerRecentMatches.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void dialog_popup() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics();
        int screenWidth = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * 0.90);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.internet_alert_box);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(screenWidth, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        Button btnNo = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
        Button btnYes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);

        btnNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
        btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!Utils.isNetworkConnected(getContext())){
                    dialog_popup();
                }
                else{
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    new TabJson().execute();
                }
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
    public class TabJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        String jsonStr = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Utils.Pdialog(getContext());
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            jsonStr = new CallAPI().GetResponseGetMethod(url);
            exeption_flag=0;
            status_flag = 0;
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    if (jsonStr.equals("IO") || jsonStr.equals("MalFormed") || jsonStr.equals("NotResponse")) {
                        exeption_flag = 1;
                    } else {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        if (obj.has("status") && !obj.isNull("status")) {
                            if (obj.getString("status").equals("false") || obj.getString("status").equals("403")) {
                                status_flag = 1;
                            } else {
                                JSONObject data = obj.getJSONObject("data");
                                JSONArray card = data.getJSONArray("cards");

                                PagerLength = 0;
                                lst_obj = new ArrayList<>();
                                list_status = new ArrayList<>();
                                lst_key = new ArrayList<>();
                                lst_key2 = new ArrayList<>();

                                arr_completed = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (int i = 0; i < card.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject card_obj = card.getJSONObject(i);
                                    if (card_obj.getString("status").equals("started")) {
                                        PagerLength++;
                                        lst_obj.add(card_obj);
                                        list_status.add(card_obj.getString("status"));
                                        lst_key.add(card_obj.getString("key"));
                                    }
                                    if (card_obj.getString("status").equals("notstarted")) {
                                        PagerLength++;
                                        lst_obj.add(card_obj);
                                        list_status.add(card_obj.getString("status"));
                                        lst_key.add(card_obj.getString("key"));
                                    }
                                    if (card_obj.getString("status").equals("completed")) {
                                        arr_completed.add(card_obj);
                                        lst_key2.add(card_obj.getString("key"));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Utils.Pdialog_dismiss();

            if (status_flag == 1 || exeption_flag==1) {
                dialog_popup();
            } else {
                Recent_header_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                LiveAdapter adapterTabRecent = new LiveAdapter(getContext(), lst_obj, PagerLength, list_status, lst_key);
                adapterTabRecent.notifyDataSetChanged();
                pagerRecentMatches.setAdapter(adapterTabRecent);
                pagerRecentMatches.setCurrentItem(current_pos);


                ScheduleAdapter CmAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(getContext(), arr_completed, lst_key2);
                CmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                completed_listview.setAdapter(CmAdapter);
            }
        }
    }

    private void findViews() {

        pagerRecentMatches = (ViewPager) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.pager_recent_matches);
        imgOneSliderRecent = (ImageView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_one_slider_recent);
        imgTwoSliderRecent = (ImageView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_two_slider_recent);
        imgThreeSliderRecent = (ImageView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_three_slider_recent);
        imgFourSliderRecent=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_four_slider_recent);
        imgFiveSliderRecent=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_five_slider_recent);
        imgSixSliderRecent=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_six_slider_recent);
        imgSevenSliderRecent = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_seven_slider_recent);
        imgEightSliderRecent = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_eight_slider_recent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

}
```

After load the data from the server it passed to the onPost() i called an adapter which extends BaseAdpter

Here is my BaseAdapter

package adapter;

```
public class ScheduleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private List<JSONObject> arr_schedule;
    private List<String> arr_matchKey;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;
    int flag = 0;
    String time="";
    String status="";
    String match_title = "";
    String match_key="";

    public ScheduleAdapter(Context context,List<JSONObject> arr_schedule,List<String> arr_matchKey){
        this.context=context;
        this.arr_schedule=arr_schedule;
        this.arr_matchKey=arr_matchKey;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.arr_schedule.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.arr_schedule.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class Holder{
        TextView txt_one_country_name;
        TextView txt_two_country_name;
        TextView txt_venue;
        TextView txtTimeGMT;
        TextView txtDate;
        TextView txtTimeIST;
        ImageView team_one_flag_icon;
        ImageView team_two_flag_icon;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Holder holder=new Holder();
        String[] parts;
        String[] state_parts;
        String[] match_parts;
        Typeface tf=null;
        String winner_team = "";
        String final_Score="";
        String now_bat_team="",team_name="";
        String related_status="";

        if(convertView==null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recent_home_layout, null);

            holder.txt_one_country_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_one_country_name);
            holder.txt_two_country_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_two_country_name);
            holder.txt_venue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.venue);
            holder.txtTimeIST = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_timeist);
            holder.txtTimeGMT = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_timegmt);
            holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
            holder.team_one_flag_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.team_one_flag_icon);
            holder.team_two_flag_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.team_two_flag_icon);

            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getResources().getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf");

            holder.txt_one_country_name.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.txt_two_country_name.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.txt_venue.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.txtTimeIST.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.txtTimeGMT.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.txtDate.setTypeface(tf);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        try {
            String overs="";
            String wickets_now="";
            String now_runs="";
            String[] over_parts;

            time = "";
            JSONObject mainObj = this.arr_schedule.get(position);

            status = mainObj.getString("status");

            String name = mainObj.getString("short_name");
            String state = mainObj.getString("venue");
            String title = mainObj.getString("title");
            related_status=mainObj.getString("related_name");

            JSONObject start_date = mainObj.getJSONObject("start_date");


            JSONObject teams=null;
            JSONObject team_a=null;
            JSONObject team_b=null;
            String team_a_key="";
            String team_b_key="";
            time = start_date.getString("iso");

            parts = name.split("vs");
            match_parts = title.split("-");
            state_parts = state.split(",");

            int length = state_parts.length;

            flag=0;
            match_title="";
            winner_team="";

            if (!mainObj.isNull("msgs")) {
                JSONObject msgs = mainObj.getJSONObject("msgs");
                winner_team = "";
                if (msgs.has("info")) {
                    winner_team = msgs.getString("info");
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }

            match_title=name+" - "+match_parts[1];

            JSONObject now=null;
            if(mainObj.has("now") && !mainObj.isNull("now")) {
                now = mainObj.getJSONObject("now");
                if (now.has("batting_team")) {
                    now_bat_team = now.getString("batting_team");
                }
                if (now.has("runs")) {
                    if (now.getString("runs").equals("0")) {
                        now_runs = "0";
                    } else {
                        now_runs = now.getString("runs");
                    }
                }

                if (now.has("runs_str") && !now.isNull("runs_str")) {
                    if (now.getString("runs_str").equals("0")) {
                        overs = "0";
                    } else {
                        if(now.getString("runs_str").equals("null")){
                            overs="0";
                        }
                        else{
                            over_parts=now.getString("runs_str").split(" ");
                            overs=over_parts[2];
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (now.has("wicket")) {
                    if (now.getString("wicket").equals("0")) {
                        wickets_now = "0";
                    } else {
                        wickets_now = now.getString("wicket");
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                if (!mainObj.isNull("teams") && mainObj.has("teams")) {
                    teams = mainObj.getJSONObject("teams");
                    team_a = teams.getJSONObject("a");
                    team_b = teams.getJSONObject("b");
                    team_a_key = team_a.getString("key");
                    team_b_key = team_b.getString("key");

                    JSONArray team_arr = teams.names();
                    JSONObject team_obj;
                    for (int a = 0; a < team_arr.length(); a++) {
                        if (now_bat_team.equals(team_arr.getString(a))) {
                            team_obj = teams.getJSONObject(team_arr.getString(a));
                            if (team_obj.has("short_name") && !team_obj.isNull("short_name")) {
                                team_name = team_obj.getString("short_name");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(mainObj.has("status_overview") && !mainObj.isNull("status_overview")){
                if(mainObj.getString("status_overview").equals("abandoned") || mainObj.getString("status_overview").equals("canceled")){
                    final_Score="";
                }
                else{
                    final_Score=team_name+" - "+now_runs+"/"+wickets_now+" ("+overs+" ovr)";
                }
            }

            holder.txt_one_country_name.setText(parts[0]);
            holder.txt_two_country_name.setText(parts[1]);

            if(length==1){
                holder.txtTimeGMT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
                holder.txtTimeGMT.setText(state_parts[0]);
            }
            if(length==2){
                holder.txtTimeGMT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
                holder.txtTimeGMT.setText(state_parts[0] + "," + state_parts[1]);

            }
            if(length==3){
                holder.txtTimeGMT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12);
                holder.txtTimeGMT.setText(state_parts[1] + "," + state_parts[2]);
            }
            if(length==4){
                holder.txtTimeGMT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12);
                holder.txtTimeGMT.setText(state_parts[2] + "," + state_parts[3]);
            }

            holder.txtDate.setText(final_Score);
            holder.txtDate.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.txtDate.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
            holder.txtTimeIST.setText(winner_team);
            holder.txt_venue.setText(related_status);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                match_key = arr_matchKey.get(position);
                MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
                GetValue gv = new GetValue(context);
                gv.setFullUrl(match_key);
                gv.setAccessToken(activity.getMyData());
                gv.execute();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return super.isEnabled(position);
    }
}
```

This adapter set the listrow item into listview.

In ScheduleAdapter.java i set the onclick() on the convertView in which i called a GetValue class which is only implement a Asynctask to get the data and called and intent then it goes to an activity.

Means HomeFragment->ScheduleAdapter->GetValue->Scorecard

Here,
    HomeFragment is fragment which have listview

ScheduleAdpter is an adapter which set data to listview which reside in homefragment

GetValue is class which implement some important task and it passed an intent and goes to an activity(It's work as a background)

ScoreCard is my activity which called after click on the row of the listview which reside in HomeFragment.

Please, help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: Try this while you start a new activity..

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: I already implemented a intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Comment: Then try changing that to this.. And see what is the result.

Comment: Also for a suggestion.. You better remove all the parsing from the adapter.Adapters are just for showing the data and not for any kind of parsing or calculations because this can incredibly slow down your app. Do all your parsing else where and pass that values into adapter..

Comment: Its open two times but one is goes to close.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag in Listview click - isListClicked, and set flag value as false in onPostexecute method of Aysnc task class -GetValue

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(!isListClicked){
            match_key = arr_matchKey.get(position);
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
            GetValue gv = new GetValue(context);
            gv.setFullUrl(match_key);
            gv.setAccessToken(activity.getMyData());
            gv.execute();
            isListClicked = true;
        }


    }
});
```

Comment: hello it's work after goes to the activity when i pressed the device back button then i press the row all the disabled by default why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent multiple activities being opened when the user spams with touches, add into your onClick event the removal of that onClickListener so that the listener won't exist after the first press.

Comment: How and where because i am new in android

Comment: I don't no implementation please, tell me

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is you can create a model class of your json object with those field you taken in holder class. And add one more boolean field isClickable with by default with true value.Now when user press a row for the first time you can set your model class field isClickable to false. Now second time when user press a row,you will get a position of row and you can check for isClickable. it will return false this time.

Model Class :

```
public class CountryInfoModel {

  //other fields to parse json object
   private  boolean isClickable; //<- add one more extra field

    public boolean isClickable() {
        return isClickable;
    }

    public void setIsClickable(boolean isClickable) {
        this.isClickable = isClickable;
    }
}
```

listview click perform :

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //country_list is your list of model class List<CountryInfo>

                if(country_list.get(position).isClickable())
                {
                    //Perform your logic
                    country_list.get(position).setIsClickable(false);

                }else{
                    //Do nothing : 2nd time click
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: you mean my sceduleAdapter should i perform a logic?

Comment: you have to perform listview click event where you set adapter to listview not in adapter class.In your casel in home fragment onPostExecute after completed_listview.setAdapter(CmAdapter);

Comment: how i find the both the method which reside inside the CountryInfoModel?

Comment: Please tell me how? not Understand

Comment: you can create a model class with all field you getting in json object with getter and setter. I just explained only 1 field that require to perform what you want. search for how to create and use model class..you will get clear idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your custom click listener for your listview and use it. In this way

```
         public abstract class OnListItemClickListener implements  OnItemClickListener {


         private static final long MIN_CLICK_INTERVAL=600;
         private long mLastClickTime;
         public abstract void onListItemSingleClick(View parent, View view, int position, long id);

         public OnListItemClickListener() {
                 // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         }


           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int position, long id) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      long currentClickTime=SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                      long elapsedTime=currentClickTime-mLastClickTime;

                      mLastClickTime=currentClickTime;

                     if(elapsedTime<=MIN_CLICK_INTERVAL)
                     return;

                     onListItemSingleClick(parent, view, position, id);        

            }

     }
```

Comment: we to provide an implementation of onsingleClick() method inside the my adapter>

Comment: What i need to write inside my adapter when i create the object.

Comment: because we can not create an object of abstract class.